# What's the difference between zig-zags and a helixes?

Tags: solution-verification, polygons, polytopes

I've been reading through the Polytope-Wiki entry on [helices](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Helix). To my understanding, an $n$-gonal helix is a blend of a planar $n$-gon $\{n\}$ with the regular linear apeirogon $\{\infty\}$. The blend of the apeirogon with a line segment produces the only two dimensional "helix", the zig-zag. Finally, $\{\infty\}$ is a blend of itself with a point and so is a one-dimensional helix.

All of these polygons have the same graph-structure. Every vertex joins two edges and every edge meets two vertices. There are no cycles, so their Hasse diagrams are isomorphic. This means that all the helices are isomorphic as abstract polytopes.

As far as I can make out, their symmetry groups are isomorphic. Every symmetry of $\{\infty\}$ corresponds to a symmetry of the $n$-gonal helix and vice versa.

### So how do these shapes differ?

All the helices are isomorphic as abstract polygons and they've got isomorphic symmetry groups.

The only way I can see to distinguish them is via "undoing" the blending. The definitions of blending that I've come across all reference the ambient space, where we can project blended polytope onto certain subspaces to obtain the polytopes that we originally blended. This doesn't really satisfy me because I feel there should be a way to distinguish helices in a "more abstract" manner.

*Can it really be that the same abstract regular polytope can have such qualitatively different realisations?*

Am I missing some simple way to distinguish the helices from each other and from the zig-zags and apeirogons?

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Zig-zag] A zig-zag, image from Wikipedia. |
| [image: A linear apeirogon] Part of an apeirogon, image from Wikipedia. |
| [image: Hexagonal helix] Side view of hexagonal helix, a screenshot from [https://cpjsmith.uk/regularpolyhedra.|](https://cpjsmith.uk/regularpolyhedra.%7C) |

Final note: The faces of the petrial mu-octahedron are triangular helices. The faces of the trihelical square tiling are square helices. Is it reasonable to say that "skew apeirogons" are the faces of both of these polyhedra?

Comment: Reading the title I was expecting a punshline.

Answer (score 4):

A helix is a non-planar shape. Here is a much better picture of a helix:

[image]

A zig-zag is a planar shape.

Therefore a helix is not a zig-zag.

Comment: I think you are being humorous, but to clarify my question is about helical polytopes.  Planarity also doesn't help distinguish the different $n$-gonal helices.

Comment: Actually I was not being humorous, but I admit that I did not click on that link at first. Now that I have looked at the link, I now understand the nonstandard concept of a helix being defined at that link, a kind of "polygonal" analogue of the nice rounded helix in my picture. Nonetheless, their polygonal helixes are 3-dimensional, nonplanar objects, except for the special case of what they call a "digonal" helix.

Comment: By the way, you perhaps were not aware, but the here is a link to the more standard concept of a [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix#:~:text=A%20curve%20is%20called%20a,a%20fixed%20line%20in%20space.).

Comment: I don't follow your explanation. Both the zig-zag and $\{\infty\}$ have realisations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and all of the helices have planar graphs. 
The polygons themselves are all 1-dimensional as unions of line segments.
Dimension also doesn't help distinguish different $n$-gonal helices for $n >= 3$.

Comment: @Numeral If you deliberately abstract away everything that makes two objects different, the objects will be indistinguishable according to that abstraction. Not everything about geometry can be explained by graph theory. Angles matter. Skew lines matter. Distances matter. You can't fit a zig-zag on a line or a helix in a plane via isometries. That's how I read this answer.

Comment: @DavidK How would you recommend I edit the question to make it clear that my question is about abstract polytopes and their analysis via their symmetries?

Comment: The first half of the question answers itself. Viewed as abstract polygons, there's no difference. If all you care about is abstract polygons, what's the question? If you want to see a difference you can consider the space in which the figures are embedded (and its metric). If you take away the metric there's again no way to distinguish the objects. I have no idea what kind of level of abstraction there might be that's between a metric space and a space without a metric. That doesn't mean there isn't one. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not confident that my reasoning is correct and I want to make sure I'm not making a mistake.
I would have been interested to see a reason from the algebraic analysis of polytopes as to why these polygons should be seen as distinct.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer to the question

> *Can it really be that the same abstract polytope can have such
> qualitatively different realisations?*

Is "yes".

Even a square (as an abstract graph) has some qualitatively quite different embeddings in the plane. Many more in space.

Comment: Realisations are more restrictive than embeddings.
As an abstract regular polytope the square has essentially only one faithful realisation (to the best of my knowledge). Do you have any examples of abstract regular polytopes with qualitatively different faithful realisations?
Intuitively, I'd guess it can't happen for finite polyhedra but I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: Not my specialty. That said, what's the definition of a polytope in this context? If for your "helix" it's just the one dimensional graph then that's what it should/might be for the square. Since I know no more about what you're asking than what I've written, asking me for further clarification won't help you. Sorry.

Comment: An abstract polytope is a certain kind of partially ordered set. For polygons, they are essentially graphs. A realisation takes the vertices of the polygon to points in a metric space, such that for every automorphism of the polygon there is a corresponding isometry of the vertex-points. Thanks for your answer!